# Azure Data Warehouse limitation and suggestion for storagr

Tags: azure, powerbi, powerbi-datasource, azure-synapse

I am facing some issue with Azure data warehouse.  Currently I am storing all the data include master data and some large core table for the organization.  These data set are feeding large amount of power bi dashboard and report.  These dashboard are refresh at a daily based and the dataset is refresh hourly to feed live data to these dashboard.  I am hitting bottle neck when these dashboard refresh and a lot of query in the queue and end up power bi times out during refresh.  Can anyone advice what can I do to fine tune the date ware house and can anyone advice what is the best or the right storage option based on our usage?

Thank you so much !!!!

[image]

Comment: It would be recommend in this case to have Azure Analysis Service be the OLAP layer not Power BI. Refresh and queries will be better that having direct access to the DWH layer alone

Comment: What scale DW do you have? What resource class are you using? Those answers impact concurrency limits.

Comment: @GregGalloway it is at DW1500c currently.

Comment: @Jon thank you for your feedback.  I am new to the territory please forgive me if I ask stupid question.  Analysis service is a bit out of our budget, is there any other suggestion ?  I have someone recommend putting the data in the datalake container in parquet or csv.  I am not sure if this is a route I should go.  What is your recommendation?  Also the user need close to real time refresh, if I use AAS It will need to refresh the cube more frequently, will this option be very expensive?Thank you!

Comment: @GregGalloway  Thank you for your advice!  I have added the screen shot of the current situation.  at around the same time every day I will hit the bottle neck. which I am running at 1500.  Do you think 2000 will be sufficient based on that?  thank you!

Comment: Hard to tell. All that tells me is that in a 15 minute period there were 918 total queries that were queued for at least some seconds. How far up you have to scale to eliminate queuing is impossible to tell without additional metrics and without trying it. My guess is DW2000c may not eliminate all queuing.

Comment: @GregGalloway from your experience, if I want to avoid Analysis service and able to allow these dashboard to have live data, what will be the ideal solution for storage instead of Azure sql day warehouse?  Thank you!!

Comment: @burberry398 it’s really hard to say without getting into a lot of detail on the solution. Can you do incremental refresh in Power BI to reduce the length of SQL queries? Can you optimize any slow SQL queries? Do you have Power BI premium and could refresh a subset of tables hourly through the XMLA endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

DW1500c gets you 32 queries concurrent (assuming you are using staticrc10 or smallrc or haven’t messed with resource classes). Scaling up to DW2000c would get you 48 concurrent. You might start there. See documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/memory-concurrency-limits?).